# How to call a second batch file from first batch file only when a folder is empty?

Tags: batch-file

I have a batch file `x.bat` which contains this code:

```
@echo off
for /F %%i in ('dir /b "D:\xyz\*.*"') do
( call "D:\abcvik.bat" )
```

I have another batch file `abcvik.bat` which contains this code:

```
@echo off
move /-y "D:\source\*.txt" "D:\destination\"
```

Both batch files are located on drive D.

Further I have 3 folders on drive D: `xyz`, `destination`, `source`

I want that when I run `x.bat` and folder `xyz` is empty, then the batch `abcvik.bat` should be executed. (Basically, I have created a Windows task for `x.bat`, and I call it every 2 minutes.)

Therefore if folder `xyz` is not empty, `abcvik.bat` will not run. But if the folder `xyz` is empty, then `abcvik.bat` will run.

However, my batch files are not working.

I understand that I have not written the code for `x.bat` correctly.

What would be the correct code for `x.bat`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Opening a command prompt window and running from within this window

```
D:\x.bat
```

results in output of the error message:

> The syntax of the command is incorrect.

Now the question is: The syntax of which command is incorrect?

This is answered by modifying the first line to `@echo on` and running the batch file once again from within command prompt window. The output is now:

> The syntax of the command is incorrect.
>
> for /F %i in ('dir /b "D:\xyz*.*"') do

So the syntax error occurs on line with command **FOR**.

Let us look on help of this command by executing `for /?` (or `help for`):

> FOR %variable IN (set) DO command [command-parameters]

So command **FOR** expects a command to execute, but there is none. You put

```
( call "D:\abcvik.bat" )
```

on the next line and therefore this block of commands (containing only one command) is not interpreted as command block which belongs to command **FOR** by the Windows command processor.

So what to do is using for example:

```
@echo on
for /F %%i in ('dir /b "D:\xyz\*.*"') do (
    call "D:\abcvik.bat"
)
```

Executing this batch file results now in the output:

> for /F %i in ('dir /b "D:\xyz*.*"') do (call "D:\abcvik.bat" )

It can be seen here how Windows command processor really interpreted the command **FOR** and its command block. There is no syntax error anymore.

It looks like you want to run `abcvik.bat` from `x.bat` if directory `D:\xyz` does not contain any file.

A working code for this task would be:

```
@echo off
for /F %%I in ('dir /A-D /B "D:\xyz\*" 2^>nul') do exit /B
call "D:\abcvik.bat"
```

The processing of batch file `x.bat` is exited if a file could be found in directory `D:\xyz`. But batch file `abcvik.bat` is called if there is no file in this directory or the directory does not exist at all.

`2>nul` redirects the error message output by command **DIR** to handle **STDERR** to the device **NUL** to suppress it. See the Microsoft documentation [Using command redirection operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-xp/bb490982(v=technet.10)) for details. The redirection operator `>` must be escaped here with `^` to be applied on execution of command **DIR**. Otherwise `2>nul` would be within definition of command **FOR** which is not possible at this position in the line and therefore would result in an exit of batch processing because of a syntax error.

Use the following batch code with **DIR** parameter `/S` added to call the batch file `abcvik.bat` only if there is no file in entire directory tree `D:\xyz`.

```
@echo off
for /F %%I in ('dir /A-D /B /S "D:\xyz\*" 2^>nul') do exit /B
call "D:\abcvik.bat"
```

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `call /?`
- `dir /?`
- `echo /?`
- `exit /?`
- `for /?`